# How to create navigation links

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create html navigation links like this:

[image]

But I don't know to hide the html underline and how to change the default html color. Can you show me basic example how to do this?

Comment: Please show some code you've already tried.

Comment: Google "css text-decoration" : you'll learn for example how to have none (so no underline).

Comment: Try using firefox firebug to see how others do it

Answer (score 3):

```
a{color: green; text-decoration: none;}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm amusing you already have a navigation bar.

1. To disable underlined text use css "text-decoration: none;".
2. To set the color of "a" use "color: rgb(256,256,256);" or you use "color: #000000;".

   `a{
       text-decoration: none;
       color: rgb(256,256,256); 
   }`

Answer (score 3):

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li>GeForce > <a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li>GeForce > <a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li>GeForce > <a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```css
body {
    background: #000;   
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 40px;
}
li {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 14px;
}
li > a {
    color: #76b900;
    text-decoration: none;
}
li > a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

**Live demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/98RsX/)**

Answer (score 2):

To hide the underline and add colours, your answer is CSS.

Here's an example for you:

HTML:

```
<ul class="navigation-list"> <!--the name 'navigation-list' is arbitrary-->
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
<li><a href="#">About</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>​
```

CSS:

```
ul.navigation-list {
    background-color: rgb(30,30,30);
    height:35px;
}


ul.navigation-list li{
    float:left;}

ul.navigation-list li a{
    padding:4px 8px;
    text-decoration:none; /**this removes the underline part **/
    color:rgb(250,250,250);
    font-family:Verdana;

}

ul.navigation-list li a:hover{
    text-decoration:underline; /**this adds the underline part **/
    background-color:rgb(80,80,80);
}
```

JSfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/u9A5K/2/

If you have any questions don't hesitate to ask :)